# How to download to a folder in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I can download files using AnchorElement. But I have an array of download urls(3-5 files). I would like to download all that to a new folder in flutter web. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I am also looking for some solution to download file to download folder in flutter web

Comment: @STeamup,did you find a solution?